# Affiliated algebras

Tags: reference-request, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

I am searching for articles on *affiliated $C^*$-algebras* and *affiliated von Neumann algebras*. I know that Wonorowicz wrote articles about this topic and also Pedersen wrote a section in his book "Analysis Now". Do you know other references or people which research topic are affiliated $C^*$-algebras and von Neumann algebras?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you mean "operators affiliated with $C^*$-algebras"?

Comment: @YuriiSavchuk: Yes I mean this.

Answer (score 1):

You should distinguish the two almost unrelated notions: *operators affiliated with $C^*$-algebras (in the sense of Woronowicz)* and *operators affiliated with von Neumann algebras*.

The only book (as far as I know) which systematically studies operators affiliated with $C^*$-algebras is the

- E.C.Lance "Hilbert $C^*$-modules".

For operators affiliated with von Neumann algebras I would take a look at the standard monograph

- Kadison, Ringrose "Fundamentals of the theory of operator algebras. Vol I."